# Create dynamic directory for file upload in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using mongoid paperclip for uploading docs, on upload I need to select the directory (it will be dynamically created new folder, or existing folder), and need to remove and create folder, Any ideas? anyone done this before ?

Comment: You can use `:path` option for `has_mongoid_attached_file`. By default, missing directories will be automatically created. If you want to cleanup directories, you can do this in the callbacks of the model such as `before_create` and `after_destroy`.

Answer (score 0):

If you store directory of document in the record itself, you could use Paperclip interpolations to achieve what you want.

Here's how you could do it (the code is not tested, use at your own risk):

```
class Doc
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :directory, type: String

  # create custom interpolation rule to fetch directory from the record itself
  Paperclip.interpolates :document_directory do |attachment, _|
      attachment.instance.directory
  end

  # now you can use :document_directory in your url and path
  has_mongoid_attached_file :doc, 
                            url: '/system/:document_directory/:id/:style/:id.:extension',
                            path: ':rails_root/public/system/:document_directory/:id/:style/:id.:extension',
                      # other Paperclip options
end
```

[More about Paperclip interpolations.](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Interpolations)

Comment: i have done similar, but i need to create dir inside a directory, open those to fetch files..